# Constructing an std::thread via (Args&&...)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I was wondering if there is much of a difference between various ways of constructing an `std::thread` in the following ways.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void test ()
{
    int x = 5;

    auto example1 = std::thread([x] () {
        std::cout << x;
    });

    auto example2 = std::thread([] (int x) {
        std::cout << x;
    }, x);
}
```

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread, with the `example2` case, I get `x` copied/moved "to thread-accessible storage". I'm not sure what to make of this.

Does this storage help protect against [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) or something like that?

Or is the main reason for passing in these arguments directly into the `std::thread` constructor there to make calling non-lambda functions a tad simpler? For example, to avoid the boilerplate given by `example3` by using `example4`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void foo (int x);

void test ()
{
    int x = 5;

    auto example3 = std::thread([x] () {
        foo(x);
    });

    auto example4 = std::thread(foo, x);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no real difference between `example1` and `example2`. The cppreference description of the `thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );` constructor is slightly off - `DECAY_COPY`, as the standard calls it, is performed for both the functor `f` and the arguments `args...`.

In other words, the created thread has its own copy of the functor (which includes anything captured by the lambda) and any arguments you passed; this makes it harder for you to write a data race or cause undefined behavior with dangling pointers and references. After all, the lambda expression creates a temporary functor that is destroyed at the next `;`. If `thread`'s constructor didn't make a copy, you'd be in deep trouble.

Whether you choose to pass everything in a lambda, or use the `bind`-like way of passing the arguments separately, is mostly a matter of style. Sometimes it can be difficult to use the `bind`-like version, for instance if the function you want to call is overloaded or is a function template. Other times you may not be able to capture something in a lambda, especially pre-C++14.

Comment: cppreference now mentions that both f and the args... are decay-copied